# iOS Action extension presentation style UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uikit

My iOS action extension presents a view controller modally (by default I assume) from Safari.

I want my view controller to continue showing Safari's content beneath.

Normally I can do this using `UIModalPresentationCustom`, however the only options with an action extension are `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` and `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.

I tried using `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` but it seems to have no affect, still covering up the Safari's content beneath, no matter what I do.

My only solution was to change from an action extension to a share extension, which allows me to achieve the affect I want, however this risks a rejection from Apple for not using the share extension for its intended purpose.